# navigation drawer not working after asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer with asynctask in one of the fragments. As soon as I click the element in navigation drawer to start that fragment, my navigation drawer stops working even after the asynctask is finished. I am able to click on navigation drawer and open it , but whenever I click on some other item in navigation drawer, it just closes without loading that fragment associated with that item in nav drawer.

main activity code:

```
package com.example.home;

import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.fmapp.R;
import com.example.fmapp.StartActivity;
import com.example.fmapp.R.id;
import com.example.fmapp.R.layout;
import com.example.fmapp.R.menu;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Home extends Activity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mDrawerTitles;


    static ProgressBar bar;

    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;

    //public AsyncHttpUpload uploadThread = null;

    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Log.i("start","started");
        /*
        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && (savedInstanceState.getString("currPath")) != null){
            mCurrentPhotoPath = savedInstanceState.getString("currPath");
        }
        */
        bar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);


        if (UserInfo.userId == null){
            //fetchUserData();
        }
        else{
            //UserInfo.populateSpinner(adapter);
        }
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        //MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.accounts_spinner);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_logout:
                logOut();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_change_pw:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChangePw.class);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
           // case R.id.accounts_spinner:
            //  Log.i("spinner","spinner click");
            //  return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void logOut() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("logout","to logout");
        //clear data
        UserInfo.chosenAccount = null;
        //clear client cookies
        String cookieString = "";
        Log.i("number of cookies",Integer.toString(StartActivity.cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size()));
        if(StartActivity.cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() != 0){
            //HttpCookie cookie = (HttpCookie) StartActivity.cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().toArray()[0];
            //HttpCookie cookie = (HttpCookie) StartActivity.cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0);
            int login_cookie_index = 0;
            List<HttpCookie> cookieList = (List<HttpCookie>) StartActivity.cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            //TODO: search for ltsid cookie
            for (int cookie_iter = 0; cookie_iter < cookieList.size(); cookie_iter++){
                if((cookieList.get(cookie_iter).getName()).equals("ltsid")){
                    login_cookie_index = cookie_iter;
                    break;
                }
            }
            HttpCookie cookie = cookieList.get(login_cookie_index);
            cookieString = cookie.getValue();
            StartActivity.cookieManager.getCookieStore().removeAll();
        }

        //clear server sessionId
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject name = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray arg = new JSONArray();
        try{
            data.put("requestCommand", "LogOut");
            name.put("name","sessionId");
            name.put("type", "String");
            name.put("value", cookieString);
            arg.put(name);
            data.put("args", arg);
            String finaldata = data.toString();
            new AsyncHttpLogout(this).execute(finaldata);
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.finish();
    }



    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
               switch(keyCode)
               {
               case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                   finish();
                   return true;
               } //TODO:can go forward
            }
           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
       }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void fetchUserData() {

        int login_cookie_index = 0;
        List<HttpCookie> cookieList = (List<HttpCookie>) StartActivity.cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        //TODO: search for ltsid cookie
        for (int cookie_iter = 0; cookie_iter < cookieList.size(); cookie_iter++){
            if((cookieList.get(cookie_iter).getName()).equals("ltsid")){
                login_cookie_index = cookie_iter;
                break;
            }
        }
        HttpCookie cookie = cookieList.get(login_cookie_index);

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject sid = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray arg = new JSONArray();
        try {
            data.put("requestCommand","FetchInfo");
            sid.put("name","sessionId");
            sid.put("type", "String");
            sid.put("value", cookie.getValue());
            arg.put(sid);
            data.put("args", arg);
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("fetch data",data.toString());
        String finaldata = data.toString();
        //View mySpinnerView = this.findViewById(R.id.accounts_spinner);
        new AsyncGetAccountInfo(this,adapter).execute(finaldata);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
        Log.i("arg0",Integer.toString(position));
        //Log.i("arg1",Long.toString(itemId));
        //UserInfo.chosenAccount = UserInfo.accountArray.get(position);
        //TODO: fix default account
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
      // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
      // killed and restarted.
      savedInstanceState.putString("currPath", mCurrentPhotoPath);
      //savedInstanceState.
      // etc.
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    */  
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        if (position ==0){
            Fragment fragment = new OrderForm();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(OrderForm.ARG_LIST_INDEX, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mDrawerTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else if (position ==1){
            Fragment fragment = new ServicesGrid();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ServicesGrid.ARG_LIST_INDEX, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mDrawerTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
        else if (position ==2){
            Fragment fragment = new UserProfile();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(UserProfile.ARG_LIST_INDEX, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mDrawerTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else if (position ==3){
            Fragment fragment = new OrderList();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(OrderList.ARG_LIST_INDEX, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mDrawerTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else if (position ==4){

        }
        else{
            Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mDrawerTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            //((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

The problematic fragment is with position =3, the fragment's code:

```
package com.example.home;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.fmapp.R;
import com.example.fmapp.StartActivity;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class OrderList extends ListFragment {
    public static final String ARG_LIST_INDEX = "planet_number";
    public OrderList(){

    }
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orderlist, container, false);
         int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_LIST_INDEX);
         fetchOrderInfo();
         String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

         int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                         "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
         //((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
         getActivity().setTitle(planet);
         return rootView;
     }
     public void fetchOrderInfo() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int login_cookie_index = 0;
            List<HttpCookie> cookieList = (List<HttpCookie>) StartActivity.cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            //TODO: search for ltsid cookie
            for (int cookie_iter = 0; cookie_iter < cookieList.size(); cookie_iter++){
                if((cookieList.get(cookie_iter).getName()).equals("ltsid")){
                    login_cookie_index = cookie_iter;
                    break;
                }
            }
            HttpCookie cookie = cookieList.get(login_cookie_index);

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject sid = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray arg = new JSONArray();
            try {
                data.put("requestCommand","GetRequestInfo");
                sid.put("name","sessionId");
                sid.put("type", "String");
                sid.put("value", cookie.getValue());
                arg.put(sid);
                data.put("args", arg);
            } catch (JSONException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("fetch data",data.toString());
            String finaldata = data.toString();
            //View mySpinnerView = this.findViewById(R.id.accounts_spinner);
            new AsyncFetchUserOrders(getActivity(),this).execute(finaldata);
            return;
        }
     /*
     public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

            Log.i("list click","list item click");


        }
        */
    public void populateAdapter(ArrayList<OrderObj> arrayOrderObj) {
        ArrayAdapter<OrderObj> OrderList = new OrderAdapter(getActivity(), arrayOrderObj);
        setListAdapter(OrderList);

    }
}
```

Note that if I comment out asynctask line, the nav drawer works fine.

Now the asynctask code:

```
package com.example.home;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.fmapp.GlobalVars;
import com.example.fmapp.JsonUtil;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AsyncFetchUserOrders extends AsyncTask<String,Boolean,Integer> {
    protected static String USER_SERVER = GlobalVars.USER_SERVER;
    private int errorCode = -1;
    ProgressBar bar = Home.bar;
    private Context mainContext;
    private OrderList orderFragment;
    //private Arra
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public ArrayList<OrderObj> arrayOrderObj = new ArrayList<OrderObj>();// TODO: populate this shit

    private String toastMsg = null;

    public AsyncFetchUserOrders(Context mainContext, OrderList orderFragment) {
        this.mainContext = mainContext;
        this.orderFragment = orderFragment;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url = null;
        Log.i("req data",params[0]);

        try {
            url = new URL(USER_SERVER);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout( 10000 /*milliseconds*/ );
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout( 15000 /* milliseconds */ );
        //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        try {
             urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
             try {
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                urlConnection.connect();
                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(params[0]);
                writer.close();
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //response:

            try { //parse errorCode
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                String response = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();

                /*   
                InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                    Log.i("line",line);
                }
                responseStreamReader.close();
                */

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer stringBuilder = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();


                String resp = stringBuilder.toString();
                Log.i("resp",resp);
                processResp(resp);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

         finally {
             urlConnection.disconnect();
         }

         return 1;
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        //Log.i("postexec","in post execute");
        bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mainContext, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        if (JsonUtil.authSucess == false){

        }
        else{
            // Imp TODO : get to new Activity
            Log.i("ltid","populate spinner");
            //IMP TODO :UserInfo.populateSpinner(adapter);

            JsonUtil.authSucess = false;
            /*
            if (arrayOrderObj != null){
                ArrayAdapter<OrderObj> OrderList = new OrderAdapter(mainContext, arrayOrderObj);
                orderFragment.setListAdapter(OrderList);
            }*/
        }

        //this.cancel(true);
    }

    /*
    public void onStop() {
        //super.onStop();
        if(this!=null){
            this.cancel(true);
        }
    }
    */ 

    private void processResp(String resp) {
        errorCode = JsonUtil.processRespForErrorCode(resp);
        if (errorCode == 0){
            JsonUtil.authSucess = true;
            toastMsg = "Order info received";
            //TODO: parse JSON and populate user orderinfo info
            Log.i("orders", "to populate Order");
            JsonUtil.populateOrderInfo(resp,arrayOrderObj);
            //Log.i("fname",UserInfo.chosenAccount.firstName);
            /*
            ArrayAdapter<OrderObj> OrderList = new OrderAdapter(mainContext, arrayOrderObj);
            orderFragment.setListAdapter(OrderList);
            */
            //orderFragment.populateAdapter(arrayOrderObj);
        }
        else{
            toastMsg = "Something wrong";
        }
    }


}
```

Once again, nothing fancy here. still cant figure out what is making the navigation drawer to just close and not start the fragment, if it is clicked on item to start another fragment.
Thanks.

Comment: check Home.bar, maybe this ui element covered your fragment ?

Comment: Wow, that was actually the problem. Amazing. But still i dont get it why that was the problem. It would be great if you explain this to me please, I still dont get it. Also, could you post this as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will be the `Home.bar` covers your fragment? Maybe you should use `ProgressBar.show()` or `ProgressBar.dismiss()` to control the visibility of the progressbar